# How is Kubernetes API setup within Rancher

Tags: api, kubernetes, rancher

As a proof of concept we are trying Kubernetes with Rancher.
Currently we have in total 10 machines for the environment.

- 3 machines for ETCD (labels: etcd=true)
- 3 machines for API  (labels: orchestration=true )
- 4 machines as K8S worker nodes (lables: compute=true)

I need to evaluate how is the Kubernetes API being set in Rancher environment. From the K8S Dashboard there is only service "kubernetes" running in the "default" namespace on port 443.

I want to know how which containers are used by Rancher to run the API on ?
What HA model is used on the hosts with labels orchestration=true (master-master, master-slave )? API communication flow ? What can external user can get from it ?

Would be grateful for any kind of tips, links and docs.

Comment: Have you eventually created this cluster with success? We are thinking about 7 nodes HA cluster, and documentation of Rancher is not really that good on this topic. 2 compute nodes, 2 orchestration nodes (so if I understand correctly, here should be rancher servers), 3 data nodes (etcd cluster and probably MySQL cluster for Rancher?).

Comment: my personal opinion after many months of researching and few clusters: don't go with Rancher if you are planning it for production. Rancher is good for development and getting to know with Kubernetes. You should check out kube-spray. And yes, i managed to bring it up but really soon after it crashed.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, eventually I came to the same conclusion, Rancher is good intro into Kubernetes, but too limited for production-ready cluster. Kubespray seems like nice start point, better option than starting completely from scratch.

Comment: We just released Rancher 2.0, which is a complete rewrite using Kubernetes at the core. Please do check out and see if it fits your needs. @Adiqq, could you share your reasons why you didn't go with Rancher 1.6 for managing Kubernetes?

Comment: @letdotcloud Rancher 1.6 was fine at the beginning for us, very easy to create k8s cluster without almost no knowledge about it, so it was perfect way to introduce it to our team, without spending initially a lot of time to show working prototype of cluster. However kubespray with Ansible gives us more control, nothing is abstracted away, we can easily see and change every part and it forced me to learn about Ansible and k8s in depth, so it improved greatly our operation side. I can compare it to Windows vs Linux, Windows is fine, but eventually you want to really understand what's going on.

Comment: What is your Rancher's version number?